# CSS - placing images in relation to each other while also supporting scaling

Tags: html, css, carousel

I want to make a carousel-style widget that is built with 3 images and two buttons.
My problem is that this whole thing needs to be responsive and scale up (to some maximum) and down, while keeping the relations between the images.

The shape is as follows:

[image]

The pixel sizes of the images are all known upfront, and any relation that is needed can be known upfront (e.g. the amount needed to move the green and blue boxes since they are not vertically centered).

I am not very experienced with HTML/CSS, and I managed to get this shape with flexboxes and translations, but I could never manage to get it to scale correctly with the rest of the page.

I don't quite understand if this is even possible with CSS, since it requires some sort of absolute positioning / translations / etc. that ruin its box model.

The next thing I thought of trying is to use a canvas instead and draw the images myself, while letting the canvas width to stretch as it wills (up to a maximum) while I control the height in JS, since I know the aspect ratio of the widget.
I would really prefer a simpler HTML/CSS solution though.

I suppose I could do the same without a canvas - a container that is controlled by CSS for width, but I control its height, and the images/buttons could all be absolutely positioned in it, but that's kinda weird as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal can be accomplished by using percentage-based width values (heights being auto or unset) for the images at different CSS breakpoints (e.g. Bootstrap's listed at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/). Practically from an aesthetic standpoint, I suggest setting buttons to pixel values (again, differing at breakpoints). Either a container (like a div element) or the body element will be the parent element to which your images and buttons scale.

To accomplish overlapping of images (and horizontal alignment of buttons mentioned in the next paragraph), for all elements you'll need to set z-index, which indeed does require either absolute or fixed positioning. Given your elements will be either absolute or fixed in position, you could modify vertical positioning using the top property.

Give the three images auto left/right margins. Set the buttons to the same z-index as the green image so that they'll rest against the green image. Give the L button a left margin of auto and right margin of 0. Give the R button a left margin of 0 and right margin of auto.

No JS required with this solution, as you'd prefer.